Fix portrait orientation in Android application for tablet (Jetpack Compose)
As per the title, I am trying to lock the rotation of my application in Portrait but I am not succeeding, being developed for tablet every time I try to rotate the simulator, the application rotates accordingly, how can I fix this?
Edit: I have already tried with "requestedOrientation = ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT" in MainActivity.kt and also in Android Manifest with: "android:screenOrientation="portrait""

How are you trying to lock it?

i have tried with  "requestedOrientation = ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT" in MainActivity.kt
and also in Android Manifest with:
"android:screenOrientation="portrait""

Please [edit] your question to add that, so others are sure to see it. Sorry, I don't really have any suggestions for ya, other than to say that it seems to be expected behavior, at least on newer versions: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element#screen. You might also have a look at the following, if you've not yet seen it: https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/device-compatibility-mode.
